# c++ objects memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory

I have the following code

```
class Rect
{
public:
    int width = 10;
    int height = 20;
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Rect  rect;
    Rect rects;
    //rect = rects;

    cout << sizeof(Rect) << endl;   // prints 8 which is fine

    cout << &rect.width << "\t"  << &rect.height << endl;   // prints 0027FEC8  0027FECC
    cout << &rects.width << "\t" << &rects.height << endl;  // prints 0027FEB8  0027FEBC
```

My question is why there is always a difference of twice the size between address of two objects? For example 0027FEC8 - 0027FEB8   is 16. When i add another member variable of type int then the difference is 24 and so on...

Could someone please explain why there is a difference in address of twice the size of the class (which is 8 bytes). I was hoping to see the second objects member variable width at address at 0027FEC0 but it is 12 bytes forward and so is the second objects height variables address. Why is that?

Comment: [Alignment?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment)

Comment: Why should variables be stored adjacently?

Comment: There's nothing in C++ that says how and where local variables should be stored. The compiler could store the two structures megabytes apart if it wanted.

Comment: You'll have to add more details about the platform (evidently windows, though you don't say so) and compilation options, as I can't reproduce this: https://godbolt.org/z/8R2QBY

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If you saw the two structures being stored megabytes apart, wouldn't *you* think that weird enough to ask a question about it, regardless of the technical legality of the behavior?

Comment: I am running this on Windows 7 and VS 2013. I tried adding variables in between in hopes that those would have any impact on the address but no matter what i did it is always the twice the size of the objects

Comment: @Sneftel Sure, and that's why programmerdude answered the question

Comment: @SombreroChicken This seems to be a question about **why** this happens, not language-lawyering, so that is really only a small part of the answer (probably why it is a comment, not an answer).

Comment: Perhaps it's an implementation detail of the compiler you're using? Perhaps it likes 16-byte alignment better than 8-byte alignment?

Comment: @BoBTFish Fair enough. As long as OP is satisfied with multiple correct answers that's fine.

Comment: The compiler could be inserting markers between the objects in order to detect stack-corrupting bugs, and the objects still need the same alignment.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for taking the time in explaining things. I added few more int variables in between the two objects and now the difference is not twice the size of Rect class and it has cleared the misconception i had

Comment: [This MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/stack-usage?view=vs-2019) says "The stack will always be maintained **16-byte aligned**", but I'm not sure if that can be interpreted as applying to every object.

Comment: Do you check this with a debug or release build? As mentioned, a debug build could insert extra bytes between object on the stack to detect stack-smashing bugs.

Comment: @FaisalKhan *I was hoping to see the second objects member variable width at address at 0027FEC0* -- What is the reason for "hoping to see"?  What are you trying to accomplish?  If it's to have the data contiguous, then use a container such as `std::vector`, `std::array`, or a plain array, not two independent `Rect` variables.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had misconception about the size of rect and rects. Initially i thought size of those is 16 bytes and that is what i was confused about (i expected 8 bytes). Now it is clear to me that i was wrong and everything is sorted :)